# Can't see my hats on mobile version

Tags: bug, mobile-web, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I was looking at SO on my mobile, and for some reason I kept looking and couldn't find any thing about winter bash on SO on my phone, I can't see the winter bash logo on the top right, and the number of hats I have, and of course the hats I have.

[image: bugmeta]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Switch to the responsive version. AFAIK, they're not developing the mobile version anymore

Comment: @Zoe Which one is the responsive version?

Comment: Try using the desktop version instead.

Comment: Scroll down to the footer, and click "full site".

Comment: @Zoe Thank you, It's fixed

Comment: Cross-site [duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+winter+bash+mobile) of [Mobile site does not have Winter Bash pulldown in notification bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288616/289905) on MSE.